# Auto increment no postgres/sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize-js

Possuo um banco de dados Postgres utilizando Sequelize (node/express) como ORM.
Tenho uma tabela chamada students, nela existem as colunas: id e name.

Nesta tabela students, possuo vários alunos cadastrados, porém, um detalhe: o último ID cadastrado é o 34550 e o primeiro é o 30000, são provenientes de uma importação de um banco de dados anterior, eu preciso continuar contando a partir do 34550, ou seja, a partir do último aluno cadastrado. Porém, quando cadastro um aluno via API, a ID gerada fica abaixo do 30000. Sei que no mysql o campo ID sendo AUTO INCREMENT já resolveria, porém, pelo que entendi, o postgres trabalha de uma forma diferente.

Como poderia resolver esse problema?

A migration utilizada para criar a tabela é a seguinte:

```
    module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.createTable('students', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
      });
    },
  
    down: (queryInterface) => {
      return queryInterface.dropTable('students');
    },
  };
```

Print da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em postgres ao criar um campo autoincrementado automaticamente é criada uma sequence.

Quando criarmos um novo registro na tabela campo id recebe como valor default o nextval() da sequence.

Para resolver seu problema, basta alterar o current value da sequence que atualmente deve estar menor de 3000 e colocar ele como 34550.

Para isso execute o comando:

```
SELECT setval('public.students_id_seq', 34550, true);
```

Ao cadastrar um novo usuário o nextval() da sequence será 34551.